# How can I build a vanilla chunk loader without access to spawn chunks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have an iron farm on an SMP server. I want it to be loaded constantly. I know about the spawn chunk related methods (placing it there and hopper clock to there and back) but I can't build in the spawn chunks because they are rival territory. I heard about using a tamed dog to keep the chunk loaded; does that work? If not, are there any other chunk loaders that don't require spawn chunks?

Comment: Does the Nether portal work?

Comment: Can't; my server for some reason lumps all the portals together into one in the nether

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say, that currently using the spawn chunks is the only way to do it. I tested the Tamed Dog chunk loader myself and it did not work. For now, we will just have to wait until there is a feature or bug you can exploit. You could try AFK iron farming, although that is not recommended on all servers, so if you would like to know to do that I would recommend writing another question or editing this one. You could build up your power and take over the enemy territory though.

Answer (score -1):

I think i've might've found a design that dousn't requite spawnchunks.
It is quite advanced / expensive, but i think it could be worth it to load iron farm.

Not 100% sure if it still works thought.

Comment: You should include important parts of the video in your answer in case the video is no longer available someday.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using pistons to load the cunks just string them together so that the pusher goes into the next chunk.